# To creating a dynamic union query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to loop through my counter to create a dynamic sql query which should finally look like

I am trying to use this approach to get the final query but doesnt
seems to work

```
declare @CurrentRow int 
set @CurrentRow =0;
declare @RowsToProcess int
declare @FinalHistoricalQuery varchar(5000)
WHILE @CurrentRow<3
 BEGIN       
   SET @FinalHistoricalQuery =' select 11'+convert(varchar(20),@CurrentRow) + ' union '
   SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
 END

SET @FinalHistoricalQuery = left(@FinalHistoricalQuery,len(@FinalHistoricalQuery)-6)
exec (@FinalHistoricalQuery)
```

the final ouput that i am looking for is 110 111 112 but it comes as 112
Any suggestion would be helpfull

Comment: Write out the statement as you go so you can see what is being built.  With you example above you are going to end up with a UNION statement at the last item which is not valid.

Comment: yes i am only getting the last item rather than the whole build up query .i am not sure how do append the previous string value in this counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to use the counter in `dynamic query`. Try something like this.

```
WHILE @CurrentRow<@RowsToProcess
 BEGIN       
   SET @FinalHistoricalQuery +=' select id from table'+convert(varchar(20),@CurrentRow) + ' union '
   SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
 END

SET @FinalHistoricalQuery = left(@FinalHistoricalQuery,len(@FinalHistoricalQuery)-6)
exec (@FinalHistoricalQuery)
```

Comment: LEN -6 IS because of the union statement at the end ?

Comment: in this when it will come out of the while loop it will only have the last updated select since you are setting the @FinalHistoricalQuery everytime

Comment: got the answer by modifying SET @FinalHistoricalQuery +=